# How to use XY cordinates in a DecisionTreeClassifier model

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have been using the below feature data set with this format to train a Random Forest Classifier.

```py
feature = ([X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X1', Y1', X2', Y2', X1'', Y1'', X2'', Y2'',...], [aX1, aY1, aX2, aY2, aX1', aY1', aX2', aY2', aX1'', aY1'', aX2'', aY2'',...],..)

class =([5.0],[1.0],...)

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(feature, class)
```

In this example "X" and "Y" represent coordinates (x,y).  It seems like there should be a way to pre process the X dataset so that it properly represents the (x,y) coordinates.

Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Does your data set have one predictor and one response? Typically you call DecisionTreeClassifer.fit(X) where X is the matrix of predictor variables in the format where a row is an instance and a column in a predictor.

Comment: What you get is called features. They usually organized as data points, or array rows. So, to classify something according to x and y, you have to put them as first and second element in a row, and the third one, or separate in the same order, is outcome to be classified.

Comment: What do you mean by _improve the results_ ?

Comment: @MWaz I have updated the question to clarify the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @AMC I removed the "improve the results" part of the question.  That was miss leading.

Comment: maybe add a reproducible example, perhaps post a fraction of the features and class data. Btw, you cannot name a variable class in python.